# Javascript from view routing to the wrong action in the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Project environment: C#, MVC 5.0

HTML code from `Edit.cshtml`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ActiveClient.ClientName, new { 
    htmlAttributes = new { @onchange = "OnNameEdit(this.value)", 
    @class = "form-control" } })
```

jQuery / JavaScript from Edit.cshtml:

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
<script>
function OnNameEdit(val) {
    window.location.href = "OnNameEdit?Value=" + val;
};
</script>
```

Code for Action in Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult OnNameEdit(String Value)
{
    WFViewModel = (WorkflowVM)TempData["WFViewModel"];
    if (Value != null)
    {
        WFViewModel.ActiveClient.ClientName = Value;
    }
    TempData["WFViewModel"] = WFViewModel;
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Clients");
}
```

> Action that control goes to instead in the same   controller:

```
// GET: Clients/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    WFViewModel = (WorkflowVM)TempData.Peek("WFViewModel");
 // Remaining code removed for brevity
```

The view loads fine. One gets to the field to modify the contents of the ClientName and modifies the contents. 
When one tabs out of the ClientName control, control flows to the OnNameEdit() function in the scripts portion 
of the `Edit.cshtml` file. When that function completes, control transfers to the action named Edit() instead of 
the Action named OnNameEdit() in the same Controller.

This code is basically identical to the code for the Create view for the same controller, and it works perfectly

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: this is because you use  RedirectToAction("Edit"). try return View();

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @apomene, but the point is that the Action OnNameEdit is never reached in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an AJAX call, like:

```
function  OnNameEdit(val)
{
   $.ajax({
      url: 'OnNameEdit',
      data: { Value: val }
   }).done(function() {
      alert('OnNameEdit called'); 
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello @apomene, I tried your JavaScript Ajax call and it to went straight to the Edit action on the controller, not to the OnNameEdit action as intended. Isn't the URL line supposed to have both the action and the controller in it?

Comment: Hello @apomene, after a bit of poking and twisting, the following change needed to be made to your suggestion: URL: '@Url.Action("OnNameEdit", "Clients")', Thanks for the help